# to make the lights even safer

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, infinitive-phrases

I'm wondering what function the boldfaced infinitive phrase serves. Does it indicate purpose or result?

> Morris bought dozens of little telephone switchboard lights, attached them to a pair of long wires, and covered them with colored paper. Later, colored glass replaced the paper **to make the lights even safer**.

Answer (score 1):

> Colored glass replaced the paper *to make the lights even safer*.

It's an infinitive clause of **purpose**.  I can see why you were given pause, because "coloured glass" (the subject) is inanimate and therefore doesn't normally act with a purpose.  It might have made more sense to say:

> The paper was replaced by colored glass *to make the lights even safer*.

> Engineers replaced the paper with colored glass *to make the lights even safer*.

However, the fact that both of those (especially the passive re-wording) can only naturally or idiomatically be understood as clauses of purpose (rather than result) means that the original sentence should also be understood as indicating purpose.

Secondly, imagine that the engineers had made a mistake and that the actual effect was to make things less safe, so that the sentence was:

> Colored glass replaced the paper to make the lights less safe.

This now reads very oddly to me, whereas if it were a clause of result, it should still make sense.

To express the result, we should instead say:

> Colored glass replaced the paper, making the lights less safe

> Colored glass replaced the paper, which made the lights less safe

or

> Colored glass replaced the paper, which was to make the lights less safe.

Comment: Isn't the infinitive commonly used in sports contexts to indicate result?

Comment: For example, "The team overcame a four-point deficit to win the game."

Comment: "Syracuse QB spikes the ball on 4th down to lose the game,"

Comment: "Topley dropped the ball to lose the game for England as Abbott dived full-length to make his ground."

Answer (score 0):

Let's first remove the word "even": then "to make the lights safer" simply conveys that the reason the paper was replaced with colored glass was to make the lights safer. (Presumably they could make the paper quite hot.)

When we add the word "even" then "to make the lights even safer" has the same meaning as before, but in addition emphasizes that prior to this modification, the lights were (at least to some extent) still safe.